# python polynomial curve fit - coefficients not right

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have the following x, y data (in green). I would like to obtain a polynomial function that fits my curve.  The curve that is fitted within python looks ok (in blue). 
When I use the coefficients of the polynomial and I build the function by myself the results are not on the blue curve.  For small values of X, this may still fit, but for large values is totally wrong. In the image the y for x=15 and 2.5 are shown (large points).

[image]

The data:

```
x, y 
0.5883596178    18562.5
0.6656014904    20850
0.7407008741    22700
0.8310800498    24525
0.9479506185    26370
1.0768193651    27922
1.1983161945    29070
1.3837939534    30410
1.6650549531    31800
1.946640319     32740
2.3811442965    33655
2.9126326549    34290
3.6970654824    34800
4.2868951065    34987.5
4.8297935972    35102
5.7876198835    35175
7.3463468386    35050
8.9861037519    34725
10.5490727095   34285
13.2260016159   33450
16.5822270413   32795
20.5352502646   32472
25.7462680049   32475
```

The code:

```
data = plb.loadtxt('fig3_1_tiltingRL.dat')

x = data[:,0]
y= data[:,1]
#plt.xscale('log')#plt.set_xscale('log')
coefs = poly.polyfit(x, y, 10)
ffit = poly.polyval(x, coefs)
plt.plot(x, ffit)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
print(coefs)
xPoints =15.  
yPt =    (-6.98662492e+03  * xPoints**0  +  6.57987934e+04  * xPoints**1 -\
      4.65689536e+04   * xPoints**2  +  1.85406629e+04  * xPoints**3 -\
      4.49987278e+03   * xPoints**4  +  6.92952944e+02  * xPoints**5 -\
      6.87501257e+01   * xPoints**6  +  4.35851202e+00  * xPoints**7 -\
      1.69771617e-01   * xPoints**8  +  3.68535224e-03  * xPoints**9 -\
      3.39940049e-05   * xPoints**10) 
 print(yPt)
 plt.plot(xPoints, yPt , 'or',label="test" ,markersize=18, color='black')
 plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post a short but self-contained `.py` source file: http://sscce.org/

Comment: It's kind of suspicious that the even coefficients are all negative and the odd ones are all positive. What was the exact output of `print(coefs)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the way you are using the `poyval` doesn't look right to me. Try to generate you X axis with `numpy.linspace` and then apply the `polyval` on it.
Something like the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = np.loadtxt('fig3_1_tiltingRL.dat')

x = data[:,0]
y= data[:,1]
#plt.xscale('log')#plt.set_xscale('log')
coefs = np.polyfit(x, y, 10)
ffit = np.polyval(coefs, x)

new_x = np.linspace(0,26)
new_ffit = np.polyval(coefs, new_x)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label="Raw")
plt.plot(x, ffit,'x',label="Fit to Raw")
plt.plot(new_x, new_ffit,label="Fit to LinSpace")

# This is ugly. I'd use list comprehension here!
arr = np.linspace(0,26,20)
new_y = []
for xi in arr:
    total = 0
    for i,v in enumerate(coefs[::-1]):
        total += v*xi**i
    new_y.append(total)


plt.plot(arr, new_y, '*', label="Polynomial")

plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, there's a hump that does not appear in your plot...

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm seems to be working fine. You should just instead of:

```
coefs = poly.polyfit(x, y, 10)
ffit = poly.polyval(x, coefs)
```

Do this:

```
coefs = poly.polyfit(x, y, 10) # fit data to the polynomial
new_x = np.linspace(0, 30, 50) # new x values to evaluate
ffit = poly.polyval(new_x, coefs) # fitted polynomial evaluated with new data
```

Thus, the function `poly.polyval` will evaluate all the points of the `new_x` instead of the `x` coordinates that you already know.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for answering my question.

Both the solution provided by silgon and RicLeal work.

At the end, since I had several curves I have applied the solution given by RicLeal.

My data were log on the x-axis. I just modified the code given by RicLeal, and I am happy with the outcome.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a49Gi.png)

```
x = data[:,0]
y= data[:,1]
plt.xscale('log')#plt.set_xscale('log')
logx=np.log10(x)
coefs = np.polyfit(logx, y, 10)
ffit = np.polyval(coefs, logx)
print (coefs)


logxmin=math.log10(0.5883596178)
logxmax=math.log10(26.)

new_x = np.logspace(logxmin, logxmax,50)
lognew_x=np.log10(new_x)
new_ffit = np.polyval(coefs, lognew_x)
plt.semilogx(x, y, 'o', label="Raw")
plt.semilogx(x, ffit,'x',label="Fit to Raw")
plt.semilogx(new_x, new_ffit,label="Fit to LogSpace")
print(lognew_x, new_ffit)
# This is ugly. I'd use list comprehension here!
arr = np.logspace(logxmin, logxmax,50)
arrlog= np.log10(arr)
new_y = []
for xi in arrlog:
    total = 0
    for i,v in enumerate(coefs[::-1]):
       #print (v)
       total += v*xi**i
    new_y.append(total) 


    plt.semilogx(arr, new_y, '*', label="Polynomial")

 coeffs=  [6.85869364,     -92.86678553,  343.39375022,           -555.52532934,  434.18179364,
     -152.82724751,     9.71300951,   21.68653301,  -35.62838377,   28.3985976,
      27.04762122]
 new_testy = []
 for xi in arrlog:
 total = 0
    for i,v in enumerate(coeffs[::-1]):
       #print (v)
         total += v*xi**i
    new_testy.append(total)          
 plt.semilogx(arr, new_testy, 'o', label="Polynomial")         
 plt.legend(loc=2)
 plt.show()
```